# The Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core plugin does not work on my Xamarin iOS project

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am following the steps for installing the Firebase SDK.

All the steps were followed closely but Firebase does not communicate with the application to verify the correct installation of the SDK, the following code is registered in the AppDelegate class:

```
Firebase.Core.App.Configure();
```

[image]

I already tried with all the versions (available for Xamarin) of the Plugin Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core and the result is the same.

Comment: Review the output of the iOS device log to Firebase failure/issue messages

Comment: Have a look at this article.Some Certificate settings is needed.https://xamarinlatino.com/xamarin-forms-firebase-cloud-messaging-ios-setup-1961a91d4055

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found by installing the Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Analytics library.